# Trouble selecting an element with jQuery .next()

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I'm new to jQuery and having trouble with the .next() selector.

When I click the `h3` element my `p` element slides up and down to reveal the content just fine. However, when I click the `h3` I'd also like the div `<div class="sqs-block button-block sqs-block-button" data-block-type="53">` to also slideUp.

I have multiple instances of the below code on the page, so when I click the `h3` I need the associated `p` and div to collapse together.

```js
$("div > p").slideUp();
$("div.sqs-block.button-block.sqs-block-button").slideUp();

$("div > h3").click(function() {
  $(this).next("div > p").slideToggle("slow");
  $("div.sqs-block.button-block.sqs-block-button").next().slideToggle("slow");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="row sqs-row">
  <div class="col sqs-col-5 span-5">
    <div class="sqs-block html-block sqs-block-html" data-block-type="2">
      <div class="sqs-block-content">
        <h3 style="white-space:pre-wrap;">Title goes here</h3>
        <p class="sqsrte-small" style="white-space:pre-wrap;">
          Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do
        </p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="sqs-block button-block sqs-block-button" data-block-type="53">
      <div class="sqs-block-content">
        <div class="sqs-block-button-container--left" data-animation-role="button" data-alignment="left" data-button-size="small">
          <a href="" class="sqs-block-button-element--small sqs-block-button-element" data-initialized="true">Book me in!</a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need to navigate up the DOM before using next.

Here is one way to do that:

```js
$("div > p").slideUp();
$("div.sqs-block.button-block.sqs-block-button").slideUp();

$("div > h3").click(function() {
  $(this).next("div > p").slideToggle("slow");
  $(this).parent().parent().next("div.sqs-block.button-block.sqs-block-button").slideToggle("slow");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="row sqs-row">
  <div class="col sqs-col-5 span-5">
    <div class="sqs-block html-block sqs-block-html" data-block-type="2">
      <div class="sqs-block-content">
        <h3 style="white-space:pre-wrap;">Title goes here</h3>
        <p class="sqsrte-small" style="white-space:pre-wrap;">
          Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do
        </p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="sqs-block button-block sqs-block-button" data-block-type="53">
      <div class="sqs-block-content">
        <div class="sqs-block-button-container--left" data-animation-role="button" data-alignment="left" data-button-size="small">
          <a href="" class="sqs-block-button-element--small sqs-block-button-element" data-initialized="true">Book me in!</a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: Re your [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65290818/is-new-date-unreliable?noredirect=1#comment115427442_65290818) on a deleted, well, question: Of course, you're always welcome. :-)

Answer (score 0):

A very common pattern is to use `closest()` to look up to a common parent and then use `find()` to look within that parent for another element

```js
$("div > p").slideUp();
$("div.sqs-block.button-block.sqs-block-button").slideUp();

$("div > h3").click(function() {
  $(this).next("p").slideToggle("slow");
  $(this).closest('.col').find("div.sqs-block.button-block.sqs-block-button").slideToggle("slow");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="row sqs-row">
  <div class="col sqs-col-5 span-5">
    <div class="sqs-block html-block sqs-block-html" data-block-type="2">
      <div class="sqs-block-content">
        <h3 style="white-space:pre-wrap;">Title goes here</h3>
        <p class="sqsrte-small" style="white-space:pre-wrap;">
          Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do
        </p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="sqs-block button-block sqs-block-button" data-block-type="53">
      <div class="sqs-block-content">
        <div class="sqs-block-button-container--left" data-animation-role="button" data-alignment="left" data-button-size="small">
          <a href="" class="sqs-block-button-element--small sqs-block-button-element" data-initialized="true">Book me in!</a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```